How to use Notifications Web API
There is a basic example that shows how Notifications Web API works.
The example works well in Windows and Linux with Firefox/Chrome web browsers.
However, the example doesn't show any notifications in Android with Chrome/Brave web browsers.
I cannot find any information in Web API documentation of how to use Notifications in Android. As well, there is no any direct information that Notifications API doesn't work in Android.
Does Android supports the Web API Notifications?
URL of the example https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/online-html-editor?id=a4376932-8096-4af9-aacf-c23accdcd205
Code:


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Notifications example</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

        <!-- Bootstrap/JQuery. -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-xOolHFLEh07PJGoPkLv1IbcEPTNtaed2xpHsD9ESMhqIYd0nLMwNLD69Npy4HI+N" crossorigin="anonymous" />
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-+sLIOodYLS7CIrQpBjl+C7nPvqq+FbNUBDunl/OZv93DB7Ln/533i8e/mZXLi/P+" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>
    <body class="container mt-3">
        <h2 class="mt-5">Notifications example</h2>

        <p>This example use only JavaScript. No server side used.</p>

        <input type="button" id="subscribe" value="Subscribe" class="btn btn-success" /><br />

        <button onclick="notifyMe()" class="btn btn-info mt-3">Notify me!</button>

        <button onclick="notifyMeWith7SecDelay()" class="btn btn-info mt-3">Notify me with 7 sec delay!</button>

        <script>
            $("#subscribe").on("click", function () {
                let promise = Notification.requestPermission();
            });

            function notifyMe() {
                if (!("Notification" in window)) {
                    alert("This browser does not support desktop notification");
                } else if (Notification.permission === "granted") {
                    const notification = new Notification("Hi there!", {
                        body: "Is an example of a notification"
                    });
                } else if (Notification.permission !== "denied") {
                    Notification.requestPermission().then((permission) => {
                        if (permission === "granted") {
                            const notification = new Notification("Hi there!", {
                                body: "Is an example of a notification"
                            });
                        }
                    });
                }
            }

            function notifyMeWith7SecDelay() {
                setTimeout(notifyMe, 7000);
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>




What’s your question? [ask]

@esqew Post has been updated. The question is "Could Web API Notifications be used in Android?"

They can, but in limited contexts and with varying levels of support for individual features. Have you reviewed any resources listing browser compatibility/support for all the different aspects of the Web Notification API like MDN or Caniuse?

@esqew Specifications from MDN and Caniuse shows that Android Chrome doesn't support only Notifications constructor and all other things are supported. But it doesn't make any sense. If Chrome doesn't support the constructor then Notification message basically cannot be created.

I managed to use Android Firefox to fire the Notification message. However it works only when browser is active and the example web page is active. In other words is useless.

If Chrome doesn't support the constructor then Notification message basically cannot be created. - that's because you don't need Notification constructor to handle push notifications

@Jaromanda The question is about Notifications not Push Notifications. How I can use Notification without constructor?

@BrilliantContract I know what the question is about, I was explaining why not supporting the Notification constructor can make sense :p
